# Is it possible to have biological sex as x in a mediation model if you want to compare male and female findings?

Tags: mediation

I am currently working on my thesis and am interested in exploring the relationship between biological sex (female or male) and 2 interval variables related to parenting and development. I made a mediation model in which biological sex is the x, one of the interval variables is Y, and the other interval variable the M. I am now wondering whether it is possible (and meaningful?) to conduct this analysis in this way. I get stuck at how to compare male and female in this model, because usually one of them is coded as 0. My hypothesis is that males receive less of M, which leads to more Y. Conversely, females get more M, which leads to less Y. My supervisor and I get stuck on whether mediation is fitting for my research question, because the model looks very logical, but we get stuck in how to compare findings. I am not comfortable with posting my full research question and I do not know whether it is possible to fully answer this question with this information. If Mediation is not fitting for these hypotheses, what would you recommend? Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: The zero-coding will influence the coefficients on the a and c paths, but it doesn't influence your overall model. The mediation sounds like an appropriate test of your hypothesis (assuming that your data meets the assumptions for a mediation model). Can you give more detail on what you're stuck on? What kind of comparison would you want to do?

Comment: @DavidB Thank you so much for responding! My supervisor said that it would be impossible to compare female and male findings with this mediation model and that it is theoretically sound but that it would not be practical.  I would love to see if being male --> + M ---> --- Y and I expect that this relationship is different for females. Would I be able to derive this from this mediation model?

Comment: I would agree with your advisor. The mediation model *is* the test of your hypothesis. What you've described for sex-only analyses doesn't make sense - remember that mediation is just fancy regression. You can't do a regression if one variable has no variance (i.e., sex is only M or only F).